# Unknown reason for multiple re-render Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, optimization, next.js

i have a lot of re-render in my nextjs app , when i checked react dev-tools i see kind of unnecessary re-render

[image: react dev tools output]

and here is my states

```
const router = useRouter()
     const [currentuser, setcurrentuser] = useState(); // this is the hooks 2
     const [d, setd] = useState(null); // this is the hooks 3
      console.log(d)
      if(!d){
        (async () => {
          const s = await getSession();
          (s)?setd({accessToken:s.accessToken}):"";
          // (s)?d=s.accessToken:"";
        })()
      }

      useEffect(() => {
    if (d) {
      (async () => {
        const cu = await getCurrentUser(await getSession(),router);
        (cu)?setcurrentuser(cu.data ):"";
      })()
    }
  },[d]);
  const { t } = useTranslation('navbar')
```

and when i check consol.log  to see the value of my state i find that the value is the same on each render and the state did not realy changed ...
i want to know is there other reason for these renders , and eliminate it if it was unnecessary.

Comment: Reducing renders is not a problem to be solved; it's a solution to a problem - bad performance. If you are not noticing bad performance, then you probably don't need to worry about optimizing renders. Renders are fast. If they aren't, you use solutions like memoization to fix that. Otherwise just let React do its thing.

Comment: That said, `React.StrictMode` intentionally causes extra renders in development. And any time a parent component re-renders, all its children re-render as well. Those may be some of the reasons you're seeing what you're seeing